# Modify .left height depending on .right height

Tags: css, height

I created a test HTML Document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  html {
    background-color:#ff8700
}

#header {
    width:99%;
    height:70px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1
}

.left {
    width:5%;
    height:400px;
    /* Make the same of .right ? */
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:5px;
    float:left
}

.right {
    width:94%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:orange;
    border-radius:5px;
    float:right
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:-15px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:5px;
    clear:both
}

h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-family:cursive
}

</style>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><h1>Test Site</h1></div><br>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"><h2 style="margin-top: 40px">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod, libero ac ullamcorper consequat, nunc justo placerat neque, eget fringilla odio massa vitae dui. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas dapibus purus in arcu lobortis pharetra. Quisque sed augue libero, vitae bibendum tortor. Curabitur mi lacus, tristique quis venenatis non, imperdiet eget sapien. Quisque nunc ligula, commodo nec pellentesque sed, malesuada id lorem. Proin non orci consequat elit lacinia scelerisque id eu lacus. Integer eu sem nec orci facilisis ultricies. Nam fermentum, quam ac vehicula porta, lectus tortor porta libero, in imperdiet tellus urna ac purus. Sed nec nulla arcu, quis lobortis dui. Suspendisse feugiat accumsan blandit. Quisque semper fermentum ligula quis vehicula. Vestibulum in magna accumsan est dapibus sodales. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla ullamcorper quam a nulla iaculis vel facilisis quam sollicitudin. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod, libero ac ullamcorper consequat, nunc justo placerat neque, eget fringilla odio massa vitae dui. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas dapibus purus in arcu lobortis pharetra. Quisque sed augue libero, vitae bibendum tortor. Curabitur mi lacus, tristique quis venenatis non, imperdiet eget sapien. Quisque nunc ligula, commodo nec pellentesque sed, malesuada id lorem. Proin non orci consequat elit lacinia scelerisque id eu lacus. Integer eu sem nec orci facilisis ultricies. Nam fermentum, quam ac vehicula porta, lectus tortor porta libero, in imperdiet tellus urna ac purus. Sed nec nulla arcu, quis lobortis dui. Suspendisse feugiat accumsan blandit. Quisque semper fermentum ligula quis vehicula. Vestibulum in magna accumsan est dapibus sodales. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Test text 1</li>
            <li>Test text 2</li>
            <li>Test text 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">(c) 2012 thisisonlyatest.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can test it [here](http://htmledit.squarefree.com).
I want the blue block (.left) to have the same size as (.right). I tried with height `auto` and `100%`, but doesn't seem to work, instead it dissapears. I also tried to make a `.parent`  and put `.left` and `.right` into `.parent`. Then I changed `.left` height to 100%, but didn't work.

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps make a jsFiddle. I suppose most people dont bother to copy the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parent `div (.cointeiner)` with a fixed height, and apply `height:auto;` to both sides (`.left` and `.right`).

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/AXwRW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change left to 50% and right also to 50% and set their height to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use some jQuery to make the .left and .right the same height.

This jQuery plugin will take the height of the largest of elements you feed in to it and make all the elements that height.

You can get it here:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating the two blocks, use `display: table-cell;`, and remove the height directives completely. Everything else can stay the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/cwh9z/1/